# Cannot see revision in tortoiseSVN log anymore

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I did a "update to revision" (to rev. N) in the tortoiseSVN log dialog. Then I committed a change (without updating to head first).

Now a cannot see the revision between rev. N and HEAD anymore, only the one before rev. N and the last commit.

However, all the changes fro the intervening revs seem to be there.

How can I restore the log to show all revs?

Comment: Try to delete the log cache. TortoiseSVN -> Settings -> Log Caching -> Cached Repositories, and delete the cache for your repo. Then open the Show Log again

Comment: @przno Thanks. That helped. Post this as an answer to earn some reputations :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TortoiseSVN caches the log messages so it loads them up faster next time. But sometimes it can go wrong, like in your case.

To delete the cache go `TortoiseSVN -> Settings -> Log Caching -> Cached Repositories`, and delete the cache for your repo. Then open the Show Log again.